# How does the assignment operator (=) in Perl work internally?

Tags: perl, assignment-operator

Suppose num is an array,

```
@num = (1 .. 10);
```

To find its length we use the following expression,

```
$num = @num;
```

Then I used the same `$num` in the assignment below.

```
@slicenum = $num[1 .. 6];
```

I was aware that for slicing an array we use `@num` instead of `$num`. It ran well without throwing any errors. But when I print the value of `@slicenum`, it gave me 2 as a result.

```
@slicenum = $num[1 .. 6, 10 .. 20];
```

For the above assignment, I got 1 as a result.

Although the value of `$num` remains 10, please explain what is happening in the above two assignments.

Comment: `without throwing any errors...` No, you probably did not have `use warnings` turned on, is my guess. Am I right?

Comment: I am working on active perl, and as I am new to this, I have no idea whether it is on or off.

Comment: @Praveenkumar It is best to start each script with `use strict; use warnings;` — this may be annoying at first, but is an invaluable help for writing correct code.

Comment: I think someone said once that the increased control and reduced debugging time more than makes up for the short learning curve associated with using `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Depending on how much of a newbie you are, you might also want to `use diagnostics;` as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have discovered a bit of Perl magic at work. The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) (aka *the flip-flop operator* as [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) points out) `..` in this scalar context seems to want to compare the range to `$.`, which it does when used with integers:

```
$ perl -lwe '@a = 1..10; @foo = $a[1..6]; print @foo' 
Use of uninitialized value $. in range (or flip) at -e line 1.
Argument "" isn't numeric in array element at -e line 1.
1

$ perl -lwe '$x=<>; @a = 1..10; @foo = $a[1..6]; print @foo' somefile.txt
Name "main::x" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
2
```

As [darch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9719/darch) mentions, `$a[1 .. 6]` imposes a scalar context to the expression inside the subscript: `[ EXPR ]`. As opposed to when using `@a[1 .. 6]`, where a *list context* is imposed instead.

So, this part:

```
1 .. 6
```

In scalar context means `if ($. >= 1 and $. <= 6)`

When the `$.` is uninitialized, it returns `undef` (which evaluates to `0` in numeric context) and emits the uninitialized warning. When `$.` is not uninitialized (i.e. when a file has been opened and read somewhere previously in the program) it returns either true or false, or in this case `1` or the empty string. In your case, it seems to return `1`, which then results in

```
$num[1 .. 6]
```

..evaluating to

```
$num[1]
```

Which in return returns element number 1, which is `2`.

So, in short: The statement `1 .. 6` has a different meaning depending on context. In list context, it returns `1,2,3,4,5,6`, that is, a range of integers. In scalar context, it returns true (`1`) if the `$.` (line count) variable is between 1 or 6, otherwise returns false (empty string).

Here is the mention of this phenomena in the documentation:

> In list context, it returns a list of values counting (up by ones) from the left value to the right value.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma) operator of sed, awk, and various editors.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the `..` is also called the *flip-flop-operator*, which of course returns a boolean (1 or empty string)

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning explicitly that `$x[@y]` imposes a scalar context on `@y`, whereas `@x[@y]` imposes a list context.

Comment: Although x has not been used in your program, how does " '$x=<>; " statement, makes the difference in result???

Comment: @Praveenkumar It is only a way to open a file and make `$.` defined. You'll notice that I also added a file name to the end.

Comment: @TLP '$x=<>; " What does this statements means??

Comment: `<>` is commonly known as "the diamond operator" and is a file handle that reads either standard input or (if the script is given arguments), opens argument files and reads from them. `$x = <>` simply reads one line from the file handle, setting `$.` to `1`.

Comment: @Praveenkumar If this answers your question, be sure to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: The check mark next to my answer. Its how this site works, its in the FAQ. You ask a question and accept an answer.